# Вычисление расстояния от элемента до верха окна браузера

Tags: javascript, dom

Возникла такая задача: сверстать страницу с меню (навигацией по странице).
 Необходимо знать, виден ли сейчас элемент пользователю на странице, или пользователь ещё не дошёл до этого элемента. Знать это нужно для того, чтобы подсветить через **JS** текущий пункт меню, который просматривает пользователь.
Собственно, подскажите, как узнать расстояние между элементом `<h1>` и верхним краем окна браузера. Или посоветуйте ещё способы узнать, виден ли сейчас пользователю конкретный элемент. Желательно **без JQuery**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/jjmu15/8646226

```
function isInViewport(element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var html = document.documentElement;
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || html.clientWidth)
  );
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".block").each(function(index,element){
        if(isInViewport(element)){
            //тут вешаешь класс на элемент меню
            //только надо еще допилить случаи когда видно больше одного блока
        }
    })
})
```

Вешаешь скролл на страницу, в нем пробегаешь по нужным блокам, определяешь какой сейчас виден и подсвечиваешь нужный пункт меню

Comment: Хм, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: перенеси необходимый код из ссылки в ответ