# Событие jQuery при попадание элемента в поле зрения пользователя?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отловить событие когда определенный элемент попадает в поле зрения пользователя или когда элемент находится где то внизу экрана?
Почти уже сам дописал, только вижу проблема в top...не могу понять почему ошібка, уже голова не варить. Хелп!!! =)

```js
var target = $('.elem');
var targetPos = target.offset().top;
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var scrollToElem = targetPos - winHeight;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (winScrollTop > scrollToElem) {
    //сработает когда пользователь доскроллит к элементу с классом .elem
    $('img').css('width', '200px');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 2000px;"></div>
<img src="http://my.mobirise.com/data/userpic/764.jpg" alt="" style="width: 220px;">
```

Comment: `var target = $('.elem');` - а где у вас елемент с классом `elem` ?

Comment: я же говорю голова не работает ))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766850/